# How do we create a chatter group for a particular object

Tags: apex, chatter

How do we create a chatter group for a custom object. In that group I want to post feed  comments and feed posts regarding to that particular custom object and display in that group.

Comment: why do you need a group, you can directly have chatter on a record already, follow the record and so on.

Comment: We want the chatter functionality to show for a particular object so that user can easily collaborate on it without all other feed or posts coming into it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve... Are you looking to use Chatter for the setup part of a custom object, ie around the metadata of the object as opposed to chattering on a specific record of that object?
Can you give an example of what type of post you are looking to post?

Comment: Is this a standard Object (i.e Leads, Accounts, Contacts) or a Custom object one you have created yourself?

Comment: It is a custom object

Comment: How do you see your users accessing this Chatter feed? Does it need to be visible or accessible from the record page?

Does the creation/Linkage of the group need to automated for every new record?

Answer (score 1):

I believe chatter groups can't be specific to an object or record only. One possible way to achieve this could be via Apex triggers i.e.

1. Create a private group via apex or manually
2. Make required users follow the group programmatically based on your biz rules.
3. Trigger on FeedItem or specific object to programmatically post/share object required updates on the group

Answer (score 0):

An option you might want to look into: http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008atj9EAA

This is a bit more general that creates a group for an "Alert" vs a specific object. The principle is similar.